# anaconda can't recognize Microsoft C++ Build Tools

Tags: python, c++, anaconda, build-tools

I am a beginer who's just started learning PointCloud online. As I wanted to install one of the python library called *torch-points-kernels*, I failed. I input  `pip install torch-points-kernels` in AnacondaPrompt, it returns the error information as shown below

```
building 'torch_points_kernels.points_cuda' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 59, in closed
      return stream.closed
  ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch-points-kernels
```

Its error information says require Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater. However, I have downloaded Visual Studio 2019 Community along with some neccessary tools like the latest build tool. It shouldn't return me error messages like above.

After searching relevant issues, many have report they fix this problem by download and run  VisualCppBuildTools_Full.exe, which will aotomatically install a build tool . I tried the same and reboot. Although i successfully install the build tool on my computer, however, the problem still remains the same.

Until now, i have two sets of build tools. One is nested in the visual studio, while the other one is a exe file lies in somewhere in my computer. Both of them satisfy the version demanding(greater than 14.0), but both of them can't work for this pip operation.

How can i get this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Start your visual studio command prompt (start menu followed by typing "x64 Native" will likely bring it up)
2. Activate anaconda from this terminal by running activate.bat (\Scripts folder)
3. run your pip command

A somewhat preferable alternative might be to start anaconda prompt and then activate the visual studio tools on top via its .bat. (you can trace that x64 Native shortcut to a vcvars bat file that you need to run with call).  This is because some tools of anaconda packages also have a link.exe that might get called instead of the msvc one.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I tried just now but it still doesn't work.

Comment: To confirm, after running the `activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` in the terminal you mentioned, there's nothing reply or display. Is this normal？Or I did something wrong?

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat (avoid the activate.exe unless you want to specify the env as other than base)  only change after should be (base) added to the cmd.exe path lines from that step. - ties it to anaconda's pip.  the x64 Native Build Tools is what ties to msvc.  you need both tied to your command line environment.  also may need admin if your anaconda base was installed as admin.  non-admin alternative is to make your own conda environment (or better- keep your own non-admin base anaconda)

Comment: There is a (base) added to the terminal after running that command.  However, it still doesn't work. Same error was reported. 
After activate.bat, I ran the pip command both in x64 Native terminal and anaconda prompt with admin, both of them don't work.

Comment: it's not both of them separately... in the same terminal activate both before running pip.  (base) tells you conda is active.  you can check if msvc is active by typing "where cl.exe"

Comment: After activate.bat, I ran `where cl.exe`,output this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe`.But pip command still don't work after activate.bat in x64 Native terminal. I am sorry that i miss th anaconda prompt method at your first reply. I found some vcvarsXX.bat at the path x64 Native lies in. I use `vcvars64.bat` to activate and pip command, same error.

Comment: try `call vcvars64.bat` if using anaconda prompt as first step.

Comment: Tried. Same error. It's so strange that this command keep failing after so many attempts. T T

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Windows 10 enterprise, tried running the anaconda bat in both the terminal and powershell ... then tried to "python setup.py build" a tool ... getting the "require Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater" msg.

Comment: did anyone get a solution for this? I tried all the solutions proposed here and nothing works

Comment: Issue may not be lack of build tools, as people have loaded them to the path. Try figuring out what that ansitowin32 script is trying to do, and mod it.